# How to use INSERT SELECT?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table's structure:

`[Subjects]`:

- id int Identity Specification yes
- Deleted bit

`[Juridical]`:

- id int
- Name varchar
- typeid int

`[Individual]`:

- id int
- Name varchar

`Juridical` and `Individual` it's a children classes of `Subjects` class. So it's mean that same rows in tables   `Individual` and `Subjects` have a same `id`.

Now I have a table:

`[MyTable]`:

- typeid varchar
- Name varchar

And I want to select data from this table and insert it into my table structure. But I don't know what to do. I tried to use `OUTPUT`:

```
INSERT INTO [Individual](Name)
OUTPUT false
INTO [Subjects].[Deleted]
SELECT [MyTable].[Name] as Name
  FROM [MyTable]
  WHERE [MyTable].[type] = 'Indv'
```

But the syntax is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

Just use:

```
INSERT INTO Individual(Name)
SELECT [MyTable].[Name] as Name
  FROM [MyTable]
  WHERE [MyTable].[type] = 'Indv'
```

and

```
INSERT INTO Subjects(Deleted)
SELECT [MyTable].[Name] as Name
  FROM [MyTable]
  WHERE [MyTable].[type] = 'Indv'
```

You can't insert in a single query in two tables, you need two separate queries for that. For that reason I split your initial query into two INSERT statements, to add records to both your `Individual` and `Subjects` table.

Just as @marc_s said, you must select the exact number of columns in your `SELECT` statement with the number of columns you want to insert data into your tables.

Other than these two constraints, which are both related to syntax, you are fully allowed to do any filtering in the `SELECT` part or make any complex logic as you would do in a normal `SELECT` query.

Comment: `Identity Specification yes` setted only in `Subjects` table. `Individuals` and `Juradical` don't have a generated ids. So i can't insert row in `Individuals` and `Juradical` before insert row in `Subjects` couse can's be sure that get right id.

Comment: @KliverMax Well, you did not specify this in your question, so my answer has nothing related to this. I just explained how `INSERT INTO SELECT` works. But if this is the case in your situation, then your logic is correct. Insert into `Subjects` first and then in the other two tables, depending on the functional requirements of your application.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this syntax:

```
INSERT INTO [Individual] (Name)
   SELECT [MyTable].[Name]
   FROM [MyTable]
   WHERE [MyTable].[type] = 'Indv'
```

You should define the list of column to insert into in the `INSERT INTO` line, and then you must have a `SELECT` that returns exactly that many columns as you need (and the column types need to match, too)